# Php7.0-fpm сильно грузит процессор

Tags: linux, php-fpm

Фантомный баг, возникает сам по себе.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запустил strace на этот процесс выдает следующее

```
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=695, si_uid=33, si_status=0, ...} ---
getpid()                                = 10154
write(8, "C", 1)                        = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
rt_sigreturn()                          = 56
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f5c688b6a10) = 707
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {760605, 823753717}) = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=701, si_uid=33, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
write(8, "C", 1)                        = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
rt_sigreturn()                          = 140034873437968
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=698, si_uid=33, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
write(8, "C", 1)                        = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
rt_sigreturn()                          = 140034873437968
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 32743
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {760605, 824399822}) = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f5c688b6a10) = 708
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {760605, 825037147}) = 0
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 32744
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {760605, 825227552}) = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f5c688b6a10) = ? ERESTARTNOINTR (To be restarted)
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=702, si_uid=33, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
getpid()                                = 10154
write(8, "C", 1)                        = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
rt_sigreturn()                          = 56
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f5c688b6a10) = 710
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {760605, 827677677}) = 0
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 32747
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {760605, 827886974}) = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f5c688b6a10) = 711
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {760605, 828755896}) = 0
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 32748
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {760605, 828921349}) = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f5c688b6a10) = 712
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {760605, 829779218}) = 0
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 32749
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {760605, 829951780}) = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f5c688b6a10) = 713
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {760605, 830916994}) = 0
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 32750
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {760605, 831123550}) = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f5c688b6a10) = ? ERESTARTNOINTR (To be restarted)
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=707, si_uid=33, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
getpid()                                = 10154
write(8, "C", 1)                        = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
rt_sigreturn()                          = 56
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f5c688b6a10) = ? ERESTARTNOINTR (To be restarted)
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=708, si_uid=33, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
getpid()                                = 10154
write(8, "C", 1)                        = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
rt_sigreturn()                          = 56
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f5c688b6a10) = ? ERESTARTNOINTR (To be restarted)
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=710, si_uid=33, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
getpid()                                = 10154
write(8, "C", 1)                        = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
rt_sigreturn()                          = 56
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f5c688b6a10) = 717
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {760605, 835347337}) = 0
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 32751
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {760605, 835518626}) = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f5c688b6a10) = ? ERESTARTNOINTR (To be restarted)
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=712, si_uid=33, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
getpid()                                = 10154
write(8, "C", 1)                        = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
rt_sigreturn()                          = 56
```

Куда копать не понятно, после рестарта php-fpm strace этого не выдает, значит проблема гдето в этих данных

В логах php-fpm такая беда

```
    [05-Dec-2017 21:13:59] NOTICE: [pool www] child 19387 exited with code 0 after 0.231177 seconds from start
```

Comment: Покажите код, который вызывает проблему. Без кода любые ответы - гадание на кофейной гуще.

Comment: PHP-FPM просто выполняет код на PHP. Какой код выполняет ваш PHP-FPM?

Comment: @NickVolynkin если б я знал то какой конкретно код вешает систему то вопрос бы не задавал, просто бы исключил бы его или переписал, но найти его не могу

Comment: Также вам стоит разобраться, что это за файловый дескриптор с идентификатором 8, в которой никак не получается отправить "С"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема не в трейсе (который надо делать с ключом `-f`) и не в PHP-FPM, а в коде, который выполняется. Чтобы точнее понять причину вам следует:

- Найти тот код, которые выполнятся в этот момент.
- Изучить логи ошибок на предмет подсказок, позволяющих найти проблему.
- Проверить место на диске и прочие обычные проблемные места, не характерные конкретно для PHP, а для всей системы в целом.

Comment: я не спорю, что проблема может быть не php-fpm(php запускает консольную утилиту), но проблема как раз в том что найти невозможно так как софта разного очень много и что конкретно вызывает этот баг непонятно, собственно вопрос каким образом отыскать хотя бы программу которая вызывает эту проблему, если я найду программу которая вызывает багу, я ее либо совсем исключу из работы софта либо найду ей замену

Comment: грубо говоря каким образом с помощью strace или какой либо другой утилиты найти какая библиотека в данный момент нагружает процессор

Comment: по поводу того что проблема не в трейсе это вы зря так как там как раз то что происходит при этой проблеме, когда проблемы нет после рестарата, стрейс выглядит вполне нормально, извините но конкретного ответа в вашем сообщении нет, то что вы написали я и так понимаю, но найти причину не могу

Comment: Вам не стрейс нужен, не для того он. Вам под gdb нужно подцепить это процесс и трассировку стека сделать

Comment: gdb юзал от вообще убивает php-fpm

Comment: Второе, вы можете по логам найти какой запрос был в момент начала этой проблемы

Comment: еще есть какие то утилиты или способы спсб

Comment: я не могу определить в какой момент это происходит, я это понимаю, но сидеть и ловить не могу, так же есть подозрение что сначала исполнение скрипта происходит нормально потом он в какой то момент начинает подвисать по непонятной мне причине

Comment: Поставьте себе Prometheus, в нем есть штатный импортёр системных метрик. Потом по графику сможете увидеть в какой момент это началось. И потом копайте логи

Comment: Добавил в вопрос что пишет в этот момент php в логи и так постояннно, бесконечно плодит потомков и они умирают

Comment: А в access_log что?

Comment: @АнтонВеселов, нечто похожее на вашу проблему, есть на [bug tracking](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73342) И вот [еще одно обсуждение](https://serverfault.com/questions/535792/php-fpm-hundreds-of-seconds-in-the-log)

Comment: @Deonis да я находил такой вариант, да именно эта проблема с использование exec в коде, но решения так и не понятно какое

Comment: Покажите уже этот проблемный кусок в коде, если вы знаете что это проблема с exec.

Comment: FPM - форкающий. Значит вам надо смотреть что делают потомки, а не только сам процесс. Ключ `-f` у strace.

Comment: Проблемных кусков может быть много в основном конвертация через ffmpeg

Comment: гугля долго единственное объяснение что это бага PHP и давольно старая и не исправляемая связанная с exec, тестирую другой механизм